# ¿Es correcto usar el pretérito imperfecto (o copretérito) del indicativo con un nombre?

Tags: pretérito-imperfecto, indicativa

Tengo la frase `"estábamos amigos"` pero no sé si es correcto decirlo así. A mí me suena más bien decir `"estábamos de amigos"` ya que así es menos confusa la frase y se entiende mejor que a lo que se refiere la palabra "estábamos" es a el estatus o condición de ser amigos. ¿Alguna otra forma correcta que se le ocurra a alguien? Les agradezco de antemano.

Comment: El problema no es el tiempo/aspecto, sino el verbo.  *estar* no se puede usar con atributos nominales: *éramos amigos* está bien dicho como lo es *somos amigos*, pero *estábamos amigos* está mal dicho como lo es *estamos amigos*.

Comment: ¿Hay entonces alguna manera de hacer entender el pretérito imperfecto del indicativo en esta situación? Como para decir que eras amigo de alguien, y lo sigues siendo, pero la amistad está ya desmoronándose.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿existe alguna referencia que acredite que _estar_ no puede usarse con atributos nominales? Gracias.

Comment: Considero que la oración es correcta porque en este caso "amigos" está siendo utilizado como adjetivo. De hecho, podemos modificarlo con un adverbio: *Estábamos **muy/poco/bastante** amigos.*

Comment: @gustavson claro, se me olvidó que *amigo* tal cual se puede usar como adjetivo (y descubro ahora que posee además un superlativo irregular: *amicísimo*)

Comment: @guifa También se pueden usar otros intensificadores como: "Estamos re amigos". "estar amigos" es como "be on friendly terms" más que "be friends".

Answer (score 1):

La primera acepción que da el DRAE de la palabra [*amigo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2LsqDPa) la presenta como un adjetivo que también puede utilizarse como sustantivo:

> 1. adj. Que tiene relación de amistad. U. t. c. s.

Si bien "ser amigos" (permanente) es más común que "estar amigos" (transitorio), la oración "Estábamos amigos" es correcta porque en este caso "amigos" está siendo utilizado como adjetivo. De hecho, podemos modificarlo con un adverbio: *Estábamos **muy/poco/bastante/casi/medio** amigos.*

No creo haber oído nunca "Estábamos **de** amigos" (a diferencia del habitual "Estábamos de novios"), sino "Estábamos **como** amigos" (oración ambigua que puede significar: 1. Estábamos lo que podría decirse "amigos" / 2. Estábamos en calidad de amigos).

Comment: ¿Alguna vez has oído a alguien usar _estábamos amigos_? Tal vez esté bien decirlo así, pero no logró recordar semejante uso. Es por esto que pensé preguntar mejor.

Comment: @MauricioCastañeda - Yo no he oído "estábamos amigos" tampoco.

Comment: «no estábamos juntos en ese tiempo, estábamos de amigos»  http://www.elciudadano.cl/2016/09/28/328570.  Yo cuando escucho *estamos de amigos* me suena más a que *fingimos ser amigos, a pesar de ser algo más (o menos)*.

Answer (score 0):

No he oído "estar amigos" ni "estar de amigos," pero sí "estar de novios con alguien" y "ser amigos," aunque "tener amistad con alguien" o "llevarse con alguien" me gustan un poco más.

Si estás preguntando cuál tiempo del verbo se debe usar,

> Éramos amigos todavía en aquel entonces

funciona, y también funciona

> Fuimos buenos amigos, Conchita y yo.  Pero todo cambió cuando se casó.  Su esposo era un celoso y no quise causarle problemas.

Creo que "éramos" sería más común.